# jQuery eq() out of range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I have the following misunderstanding.

```
<p>adasd</p>
<p>42323123</p>
...
$("p").eq(4).html("some html")
```

I know I have only two `<p>` in my HTML so I do expect that console will say me an exception or something that will signal me I'm doing the wrong thing.

```
console.log($("p").eq(4))
```

prints:

```
prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[2], context: document, jquery: "2.1.1", constructor: function, selector:...
```

Why is it working like that?

Comment: jQuery tends to return an empty collection rather than throw an error.

Comment: @JasonP One of its (many) shortcomings, in my opinion. If you tell it to get an element, and there is no element to be had, that is an exceptional condition.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It depends... `document.getElementById()` doesn't throw an error either. I would prefer not to have to wrap calls in a try block if I'm not sure the element exists.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I suppose I can understand that `.eq()` feels like an array indexer, so you may expect the same behavior there, but it's _really_ a jQuery function that filters the collection, so I guess I would ultimately expect it to work like other jQuery functions and just return the empty collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) for jQuery's `.eq()` function states:

> If an element cannot be found at the specified zero-based index, the method constructs a new jQuery object with an empty set and a length property of 0.

If you'd like to check whether `$("p").eq(4)` has successfully found an element, you can do something like this:

```
var paragraphFive = $("p").eq(4);

if (paragraphFive.length) {
  // It exists
}
else {
  // It doesn't
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This (and many other selectors) will always return a jQuery object, regardless of whether the selector matched any elements. In the case that no elements are matched, the jQuery object returned will contain zero elements; you can test for this with `.length`:

```
console.log($("p").eq(4).length) // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Created this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBfea/)

HTML:

```
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.console&&console.log($("p").length);
});
```

This will log '2'. You can always check if there is 4 elements in your array before reading it. This is good practice in ANY programming language BTW...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there is no 4th element to return. jQuery returns an empty set for your selection.

Try:

```
var el;
(el = $('p').eq(4)).length != 0 ?
  el.html('some html') :
  console.log('did nothing');
```

http://jsbin.com/dizem/1/edit